# Invoke a private method by passing an XMl node

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing a Unit test, the code is as shown below

```
   TestAbstractionLib.UnitTestUtilsClass.UnitTestFileName = TestAbstractionLib.UnitTestUtilsClass.VisualDumpAfterValueSet;
    object[] prop = { "Patient", false };
    var methodUnderTest = Helper.GetStaticMethod(typeof(TestAbstractionLib), "GetListOfDesiredNodes");
    var labelNode = methodUnderTest.Invoke(this, prop);


    object[] prop1 = {labelNode, "BIPOLAR", "Chamber", true, 10, 10, false};
    methodUnderTest = Helper.GetStaticMethod(typeof(TestAbstractionLib), "CheckValueIsSetAlready");
    var result = methodUnderTest.Invoke(this, prop1);

    Assert.AreEqual(result, false);
    TestAbstractionLib.UnitTestUtilsClass.CheckerrorinLogFile(true);
```

In the above code snippet, I'm calling 2 private methods one after the other.
The first private method "GetListOfDesiredNodes" will return an XMLNode.

I need to pass that XMLNode as a parameter to the other private method.

As you see "labelNode" is an object type not an "XMlNode" type.

When I pass this object type as a parameter to the next method, it was throwing an exception which is shown below

```
"Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.Xml.XmlNode]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Xml.XmlNode'."
```

Please give me any solution, how can i convert this object type to XMLNode and invoke the other method.

Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: Thats because you are passing a list of nodes, and not a single node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but this should work:

```
TestAbstractionLib.UnitTestUtilsClass.UnitTestFileName = TestAbstractionLib.UnitTestUtilsClass.VisualDumpAfterValueSet;
object[] prop = { "Patient", false };
var methodUnderTest = Helper.GetStaticMethod(typeof(TestAbstractionLib), "GetListOfDesiredNodes");
var labelNode = methodUnderTest.Invoke(this, prop) as List<XmlNode>;


object[] prop1 = {labelNode.FirstOrDefault(), "BIPOLAR", "Chamber", true, 10, 10, false};
methodUnderTest = Helper.GetStaticMethod(typeof(TestAbstractionLib), "CheckValueIsSetAlready");
var result = methodUnderTest.Invoke(this, prop1);

Assert.AreEqual(result, false);
TestAbstractionLib.UnitTestUtilsClass.CheckerrorinLogFile(true);
```

Without seeing your code, but judging from your error, you need to pass in a single XmlNode and not a list. The above will cast the result from the first method to a list and then pass the first element to the second method.

Comment: You should cast labelNode to List<XmlNode> first.. Edit: as I see you are already doing that, sorry...